# Requirement already up-to-date: pip in

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

[image]

```
Wameedhs-MacBook-Air:Desktop wameedh$ cd
Wameedhs-MacBook-Air:~ wameedh$ export PYTHONPATH=.
Wameedhs-MacBook-Air:~ wameedh$ python ~/Downloads/get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-8.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip, wheel
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/folders/7x/jx8z1sg941vfxf3p7tznf8ch0000gn/T/tmpZqkyAz/pip.zip/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/var/folders/7x/jx8z1sg941vfxf3p7tznf8ch0000gn/T/tmpZqkyAz/pip.zip/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/var/folders/7x/jx8z1sg941vfxf3p7tznf8ch0000gn/T/tmpZqkyAz/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 742, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/var/folders/7x/jx8z1sg941vfxf3p7tznf8ch0000gn/T/tmpZqkyAz/pip.zip/pip/req/req_install.py", line 831, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/var/folders/7x/jx8z1sg941vfxf3p7tznf8ch0000gn/T/tmpZqkyAz/pip.zip/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/var/folders/7x/jx8z1sg941vfxf3p7tznf8ch0000gn/T/tmpZqkyAz/pip.zip/pip/wheel.py", line 346, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/var/folders/7x/jx8z1sg941vfxf3p7tznf8ch0000gn/T/tmpZqkyAz/pip.zip/pip/wheel.py", line 317, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/var/folders/7x/jx8z1sg941vfxf3p7tznf8ch0000gn/T/tmpZqkyAz/pip.zip/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip'
Wameedhs-MacBook-Air:~ wameedh$ sudo chown -R $USER /Library/Python/2.7
Password:
Wameedhs-MacBook-Air:~ wameedh$ python ~/Downloads/get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-8.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip, wheel
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/folders/7x/jx8z1sg941vfxf3p7tznf8ch0000gn/T/tmpPhatQx/pip.zip/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/var/folders/7x/jx8z1sg941vfxf3p7tznf8ch0000gn/T/tmpPhatQx/pip.zip/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/var/folders/7x/jx8z1sg941vfxf3p7tznf8ch0000gn/T/tmpPhatQx/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 742, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/var/folders/7x/jx8z1sg941vfxf3p7tznf8ch0000gn/T/tmpPhatQx/pip.zip/pip/req/req_install.py", line 831, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/var/folders/7x/jx8z1sg941vfxf3p7tznf8ch0000gn/T/tmpPhatQx/pip.zip/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/var/folders/7x/jx8z1sg941vfxf3p7tznf8ch0000gn/T/tmpPhatQx/pip.zip/pip/wheel.py", line 463, in move_wheel_files
    generated.extend(maker.make(spec))
  File "/var/folders/7x/jx8z1sg941vfxf3p7tznf8ch0000gn/T/tmpPhatQx/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 372, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "/var/folders/7x/jx8z1sg941vfxf3p7tznf8ch0000gn/T/tmpPhatQx/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 276, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "/var/folders/7x/jx8z1sg941vfxf3p7tznf8ch0000gn/T/tmpPhatQx/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 250, in _write_script
    self._fileop.write_binary_file(outname, script_bytes)
  File "/var/folders/7x/jx8z1sg941vfxf3p7tznf8ch0000gn/T/tmpPhatQx/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/distlib/util.py", line 405, in write_binary_file
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/pip'
Wameedhs-MacBook-Air:~ wameedh$ sudo python ~/Downloads/get-pip.py
The directory '/Users/wameedh/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/wameedh/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 1.8MB/s 
Installing collected packages: wheel
Successfully installed wheel-0.29.0
Wameedhs-MacBook-Air:~ wameedh$ pip install requests
-bash: pip: command not found
Wameedhs-MacBook-Air:~ wameedh$ which python
/usr/bin/python
Wameedhs-MacBook-Air:~ wameedh$ pip
-bash: pip: command not found
Wameedhs-MacBook-Air:~ wameedh$ export PYTHONPATH=.
Wameedhs-MacBook-Air:~ wameedh$ pip
-bash: pip: command not found
Wameedhs-MacBook-Air:~ wameedh$ which python
/usr/bin/python
Wameedhs-MacBook-Air:~ wameedh$ python -V
Python 2.7.10
Wameedhs-MacBook-Air:~ wameedh$ pip
-bash: pip: command not found
Wameedhs-MacBook-Air:~ wameedh$ man pip
No manual entry for pip
Wameedhs-MacBook-Air:~ wameedh$ 
  [Restored Oct 9, 2016, 6:33:31 PM]
Last login: Sun Oct  9 18:33:31 on ttys000
Restored session: Sun Oct 9 18:32:03 PDT 2016
Wameedhs-MacBook-Air:~ wameedh$
```

It says:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Wameedhs-MacBook-Air:~ wameedh$ pip install requests
```

Still I am getting this:

```
-bash: pip: command not found
```

Comment: Remove image and put whole traceback.

Comment: looks like it can't find the path to pip. is your pip in your $PATH?

Comment: yeah @Macintosh_89 in the same time it says: Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages Wameedhs-MacBook-Air

Comment: have u tried  `sudo pip install requests` ?

Comment: Yes, I did try that!!

Comment: Thanks all for the help. I fixed it! The problem was I didn't have the latest version of Xcode! 
I ran xcode-select --install before installing pip! that's it!!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for the help. I fixed it! The problem was I didn't have the latest version of Xcode! I ran xcode-select --install before installing pip! that's it!!

Comment: Could you please check this answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error also comes up when using the -i flag to specify your own resource location (ex: an Artifactory instance) and the path specified is incorrect. Verify the artifactory location by copy-pasting it as a url in the browser.